# port install subversion fails on osx mountain lion

Tags: macos, macports, osx-mountain-lion

I cant install subversion with MacPorts on mountain lion. It fails installting db46, here the log:

UPDATE: I also opened a ticket at macports: https://trac.macports.org/ticket/35570

```
:debug:main db46 has no conflicts
:debug:main Executing org.macports.main (db46)
:debug:main changing euid/egid - current euid: 0 - current egid: 0
:debug:main egid changed to: 501
:debug:main euid changed to: 502
:debug:main Skipping completed org.macports.archivefetch (db46)
:debug:main Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:main Skipping completed org.macports.fetch (db46)
:debug:main Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:main Skipping completed org.macports.checksum (db46)
:debug:main Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:main Skipping completed org.macports.extract (db46)
:debug:main Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:main Skipping completed org.macports.patch (db46)
:debug:main Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:main Skipping completed org.macports.configure (db46)
:debug:main Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:build build phase started at Tue Aug  7 14:51:37 CEST 2012
:notice:build --->  Building db46
:debug:build Executing org.macports.build (db46)
:debug:build Environment: CPATH='/opt/local/include' CC_PRINT_OPTIONS_FILE='/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_databases_db46/db46/work/.CC_PRINT_OPTIONS' LIBRARY_PATH='/opt/local/lib' CC_PRINT_OPTIONS='YES' MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='10.8'
:debug:build Assembled command: 'cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_databases_db46/db46/work/db-4.6.21/build_unix" && /usr/bin/make -j4 -w all'
:debug:build Executing command line:  cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_databases_db46/db46/work/db-4.6.21/build_unix" && /usr/bin/make -j4 -w all 
:info:build make: Entering directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_databases_db46/db46/work/db-4.6.21/build_unix'
:info:build /bin/sh ./libtool --mode=compile /usr/bin/clang -c -pipe -O2 -arch x86_64  -I../dist/.. -I/opt/local/include ../dist/../db_dump185/db_dump185.c
:info:build /bin/sh ./libtool --mode=link /usr/bin/clang -pipe -O2 -arch x86_64  -o db_upgrade -L/opt/local/lib -arch x86_64 \
:info:build         db_upgrade.lo util_sig.lo libdb-4.6.la -lpthread
:info:build /bin/sh ./libtool --mode=compile /usr/bin/clang -c -I. -I../dist/.. -I/opt/local/include -pipe -O2 -arch x86_64  ../dist/../db_verify/db_verify.c
:info:build  /usr/bin/clang -c -pipe -O2 -arch x86_64 -I../dist/.. -I/opt/local/include ../dist/../db_dump185/db_dump185.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/db_dump185.o
:info:build  /usr/bin/clang -c -I. -I../dist/.. -I/opt/local/include -pipe -O2 -arch x86_64 ../dist/../db_verify/db_verify.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/db_verify.o
:info:build ../dist/../db_dump185/db_dump185.c:211:13: warning: implicit declaration of function 'dbopen' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
:info:build         if ((dbp = dbopen(argv[0], O_RDONLY, 0, DB_BTREE, NULL)) == NULL) {
:info:build                    ^
:info:build ../dist/../db_dump185/db_dump185.c:211:11: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'DB *' (aka 'struct __db *') from 'int'; 
:info:build         if ((dbp = dbopen(argv[0], O_RDONLY, 0, DB_BTREE, NULL)) == NULL) {
:info:build                  ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
:info:build ../dist/../db_dump185/db_dump185.c:212:12: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'DB *' (aka 'struct __db *') from 'int'; 
:info:build                 if ((dbp =
:info:build                          ^
:info:build ../dist/../db_dump185/db_dump185.c:228:24: error: no member named 'seq' in 'struct __db'
:info:build                 while (!(rval = dbp->seq(dbp, &key, &data, R_NEXT))) {
:info:build                                 ~~~  ^
:info:build ../dist/../db_dump185/db_dump185.c:228:46: error: use of undeclared identifier 'R_NEXT'
:info:build                 while (!(rval = dbp->seq(dbp, &key, &data, R_NEXT))) {
:info:build                                                            ^
:info:build ../dist/../db_dump185/db_dump185.c:233:24: error: no member named 'seq' in 'struct __db'
:info:build                 while (!(rval = dbp->seq(dbp, &key, &data, R_NEXT))) {
:info:build                                 ~~~  ^
:info:build ../dist/../db_dump185/db_dump185.c:233:46: error: use of undeclared identifier 'R_NEXT'
:info:build                 while (!(rval = dbp->seq(dbp, &key, &data, R_NEXT))) {
:info:build                                                            ^
:info:build ../dist/../db_dump185/db_dump185.c:261:18: error: no member named 'internal' in 'struct __db'
:info:build         hash185p = dbp->internal;
:info:build                    ~~~  ^
:info:build ../dist/../db_dump185/db_dump185.c:263:19: error: no member named 'internal' in 'struct __db'
:info:build                 hash186p = dbp->internal;
:info:build                            ~~~  ^
:info:build ../dist/../db_dump185/db_dump185.c:288:13: error: no member named 'internal' in 'struct __db'
:info:build         btp = dbp->internal;
:info:build               ~~~  ^
:info:build 3 warnings and 7 errors generated.
:info:build make: *** [db_dump185.lo] Error 1
:info:build make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
:info:build  /usr/bin/clang -c -I. -I../dist/.. -I/opt/local/include -pipe -O2 -arch x86_64 ../dist/../db_verify/db_verify.c -o db_verify.o >/dev/null 2>&1
:info:build /usr/bin/clang -pipe -O2 -arch x86_64 -o .libs/db_upgrade -arch x86_64 .libs/db_upgrade.o .libs/util_sig.o  -L/opt/local/lib ./.libs/libdb-4.6.dylib -lpthread 
:info:build creating db_upgrade
:info:build /bin/sh ./libtool --mode=execute true db_upgrade
:info:build make: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_databases_db46/db46/work/db-4.6.21/build_unix'
:info:build Command failed:  cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_databases_db46/db46/work/db-4.6.21/build_unix" && /usr/bin/make -j4 -w all 
:info:build Exit code: 2
:error:build org.macports.build for port db46 returned: command execution failed
:debug:build Error code: CHILDSTATUS 4210 2
:debug:build Backtrace: command execution failed
    while executing
"system -nice 0 $fullcmdstring"
    ("eval" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"eval system $notty $nice \$fullcmdstring"
    invoked from within
"command_exec build"
    (procedure "portbuild::build_main" line 8)
    invoked from within
"$procedure $targetname"
:info:build Warning: targets not executed for db46: org.macports.activate org.macports.build org.macports.destroot org.macports.install
:notice:build Please see the log file for port db46 for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_databases_db46/db46/main.log
admins-MacBook-Pro:config admin$
```

Comment: I'm curious why you're building svn from source when it's presumably already installed as part with XCode? (which you've clearly installed to get Clang).

Comment: macports installs version 1.7.5, XCode installs 1.6.18. I need version 1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an older version of db.h in /opt/local/include/. After deletion of the file the problem was fixed.